# How can I print out entire excel sheet on zoom mode?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, printing

I am trying to print an entire excel sheet on a single page, larger than normal size, but my system print dialog does not have the `ZOOM and Print Options`.

How can I have a single page (zoomed out) print of my entire excel sheet ignoring other sheets in the workbook ?

Comment: Please post screenshot of the print dialog too, so we can better understand your issue.

Comment: You know better that, due to huge size of Excel sheet, entire Sheet can't be printed at once, that's the reason Print has got PAGE BREAK option,,, May be you are trying to ask how to print on ZOOM mode.

Comment: Yes this can be done, when your PC/Laptop is attached with Zerox machine, there you can put  bigger sheet and set the mode to Zoom. OR  copy your File and walk to ZErox shop, shopkeeper will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can print the entire sheet onto one page under the scaling options.

Select `Fit Sheet Onto One Page`

[image]

This can be applied to other options, i.e portrait/landscape or even when printing a selection, regardless of paper size.